# How to Maintain Scroll When List view updated

Tags: android, scroll, timer, android-listview, chat

I made and chat application in this chat application I added a a timer component every 2500 MS my listview is updated it is a chat app when anyone open this App my listview 1 direct scroll to bottom anyone help me here is my code

[Click Me to show Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFmRx.jpg)

Comment: Hey welcome to S.O. Please have a look at this :- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please add some necessary code and explain your problem in that so that someone can help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the scrolling position by updating the `ArrayList` of your `ListView` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter.

```
if(listView.getAdapter()==null)
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
else{
   adapter.updateList(newData); 
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

`notifyDataSetChanged()` will just refresh the view and maintain it's scroll position.